# Frames drop when it comes to the last image - Android FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android

I'm using the code `ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 0.2 -pattern_type sequence -framerate 25 -i /Source_Folder/Temp/a%d.jpg Dest_Folder/name.mp4;` When I execute it for a number of images, I always lose frames in the last image. Ex: If every image comes up for 3 seconds each, the last one just half a second or so short. What should I change in the above command?

Comment: I don't know if Android-based FFMpeg is identical to the PC based version.  If it's not, you might do better on the Android site (hover over the Android tag).

Comment: It's similar to the PC based version. It's the same FFMPEG wrapped around java to work with Android.

Comment: Solved: need to use `-vf fps=25` instead of `-framerate 25` after `pattern_type`

Comment: How about posting an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: need to use -vf fps=25 instead of -framerate 25 after pattern_type sequence fps gives constant framerate forcibly unlike framerate

Comment: It didn't work for me. When I used it like this instead of -framerate, the command to create video stopped working. I am not using pattern_type sequence. Do I need to use that?

Comment: And what should be the values for -framerate and -vf fps parameters as I need to show each frame for about 5 seconds per frame?

Comment: To show for 5 seconds for each frame, take -framerate 1/5 or 0.2. -vf fps is the frames per second. The difference is -framerate is used for the seconds each image appears and -vf is for the fps of the video itself.